# How to dynamically load an image in react

Tags: reactjs, jsx

How can I correctly load this image?

```
import image_1 from "../../static_media/1.png"

handleClick = async (e) => {
    
    this.loadImage({
        "0": {
            name: "1.png",
            image: image_1,
            backend_address: await fetch(image_1).then(res => res.blob())
        }})
    }
```

When I do `console.log(this.state.files[0])`

I get

> backend_address: Blob {size: 736023, type: 'image/png'} image:
> "/static/media/1.46b58831.png" name: "1.png" [[Prototype]]: Object

When I do the following

```
<Image src={this.state.files[0].image} />
```

I get

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'image')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
  <Image src={this.state.files[0]?.image} />
```